# What webpack loader can require a library in every file matched by a pattern?

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I've got a number of files in `some/path/*.cjsx`, compiled using the `coffee` and `cjsx` loader. They all have `React = require('react')`, and I was wondering if there's a way to make this DRY without assigning `React` to a global variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [imports-loader](https://github.com/webpack/imports-loader).

```
{
  test: /\.cjsx/,
  loader: 'imports?React=react',
}
```